# 2 different possibles types for 1 variable

Tags: java, variables, types

I want to do exactly this in Java:

```
boolean b;
if (b) {
    //I want that a variable "imp" be of type HashMap   
} else {
    //I whant that a variable "imp" be of type LinkedHashMap
}
```

`HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` are implementation of interface map.

I think use a tuple `(HashMap, LinkedHashMap)` but this dirties so much of the code.

Comment: `interface` not `interfaz`. Besides that what's the problem with `Map<K,V> imp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare `imp` as `Map`, parametrized with your desired type parameters, and assign it with the concrete type.

Both `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` are `Map`s and can be referenced as such.

```
Map<MyKey, MyValue> imp = null;
if (b) {
   imp = new HashMap<MyKey, MyValue>();
} else {
   imp = new LinkedHashMap<MyKey, MyValue>();
}
```

Comment: If `imp` can never be `null` I'd not initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd shoot for

`Map<MyKey, MyValue> imp = b ? new HashMap<>() : new LinkedHashMap<>();`

Note the use of the *diamond operator*: there's no need to spell the generics out long-hand.

Using the ternary conditional operator in this way means that `imp` is never in an undefined state between declaration and initialisation.

Comment: thanks men, I had saved a lot of time if I had asked before

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the inheritance tree in the collection

[image]

as you can see both classes can be implemented as a Map

so you can do:

```
Map<FooKey, FooValue> implementedMap = null;
if (b) {
   implementedMap= new HashMap<FooKey, FooValue>();
} else {
   implementedMap= new LinkedHashMap<FooKey, FooValue>();
}
```